# How do I access an element in a JSON array in KQL with a non simple name?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a query where I need to extract the value of an element for further processing

```
InsightsMetrics
| where Name =="istio_requests_total"
| distinct Tags
| extend Tags = todynamic(Tags)
| extend clusterId = Tags['container-azm.ms/clusterId']
```

But using 'container-azm.ms/clusterId' is not valid it seems, I have tried various types of escaping and tostring() but to no avail.
I have also tried bag_unpack but I still have the same trouble with accessing the resulting column.
Any help is appreciated.

Sample data:

```
datatable (Tags: dynamic)[
dynamic ({"app":"istio-ingressgateway","chart":"gateways","connection_security_policy":"unknown","container.azm.ms/clusterId":"/subscriptions/060acc24-d63a/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/halted","container.azm.ms/clusterName":"kiwikube","destination_app":"unknown","destination_canonical_revision":"latest","destination_canonical_service":"vhs-node","destination_cluster":"Kubernetes","destination_principal":"spiffe://cluster.local/ns/default/sa/default", "destination_service_namespace":"default","destination_version":"unknown","destination_workload":"mhs-node","destination_workload_namespace":"default","grpc_response_status":"","heritage":"Tiller","hostName":"aks-system-33525945-vmss000001","install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource":"unknown","istio":"ingressgateway","istio.io/rev":"default","kubernetes.io/config.seen":"2022-05-11T14:50:38.9201780Z","kubernetes.io/config.source":"api","namespace":"istio-system","operator.istio.io/component":"IngressGateways","pod-template-hash":"755d6cb48f","pod_name":"istio-ingressgateway-755d588hf-b5phq","prometheus.io/path":"/stats/prometheus","prometheus.io/port":"15020","prometheus.io/scrape":"true","release":"istio","reporter":"source","request_protocol":"http","response_code":"0","response_flags":"DC","service.istio.io/canonical-name":"istio-ingressgateway","service.istio.io/canonical-revision":"latest","sidecar.istio.io/inject":"false","source_app":"istio-ingressgateway","source_canonical_revision":"latest","source_canonical_service":"istio-ingressgateway","source_cluster":"Kubernetes","source_principal":"spiffe://cluster.local/ns/istio-system/sa/istio-ingressgateway-service-account","source_version":"unknown","source_workload":"istio-ingressgateway","source_workload_namespace":"istio-system"}),
]
```

Comment: Please provide a data sample (for `Tags` would be enough), preferably as a datatable

Comment: Sure, thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ouch :-)

Your key should start with `container.azm` (`conteiner` **dot** `azm`)

```
datatable (Tags: dynamic)[
dynamic ({"app":"istio-ingressgateway","chart":"gateways","connection_security_policy":"unknown","container.azm.ms/clusterId":"/subscriptions/060acc24-d63a/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/halted","container.azm.ms/clusterName":"kiwikube","destination_app":"unknown","destination_canonical_revision":"latest","destination_canonical_service":"vhs-node","destination_cluster":"Kubernetes","destination_principal":"spiffe://cluster.local/ns/default/sa/default", "destination_service_namespace":"default","destination_version":"unknown","destination_workload":"mhs-node","destination_workload_namespace":"default","grpc_response_status":"","heritage":"Tiller","hostName":"aks-system-33525945-vmss000001","install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource":"unknown","istio":"ingressgateway","istio.io/rev":"default","kubernetes.io/config.seen":"2022-05-11T14:50:38.9201780Z","kubernetes.io/config.source":"api","namespace":"istio-system","operator.istio.io/component":"IngressGateways","pod-template-hash":"755d6cb48f","pod_name":"istio-ingressgateway-755d588hf-b5phq","prometheus.io/path":"/stats/prometheus","prometheus.io/port":"15020","prometheus.io/scrape":"true","release":"istio","reporter":"source","request_protocol":"http","response_code":"0","response_flags":"DC","service.istio.io/canonical-name":"istio-ingressgateway","service.istio.io/canonical-revision":"latest","sidecar.istio.io/inject":"false","source_app":"istio-ingressgateway","source_canonical_revision":"latest","source_canonical_service":"istio-ingressgateway","source_cluster":"Kubernetes","source_principal":"spiffe://cluster.local/ns/istio-system/sa/istio-ingressgateway-service-account","source_version":"unknown","source_workload":"istio-ingressgateway","source_workload_namespace":"istio-system"}),
]
| project Tags["container.azm.ms/clusterId"]
```

| Tags_container.azm.ms/clusterId |
| --- |
| /subscriptions/060acc24-d63a/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/halted |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA41VTW/iMBC9V%20p/QJxaqU4CNC3l2pWqarV72Z62qtDgOMSLY7seB8R%20/PcdJwFC%20diFC8y82PNm3rxk4Ok7U6J39QJznPSytYZS8uvXy4v2Z%20/qVx%20s7U/6Er00TOq5E4hz8GIF6/5NnxfgPKXbCIaQ0VpwQuspCl456ddTa5Tka8JVeqHNSjcwD1ILF8HPMiox5qpCL9xzRrAYqxlyJ204BuPkLgHOh7csuxtBTBWYynHx5ExlMfYCfWydWcpMOIy/SO4MmtxHj5sbvgm3lFzEJWiYi%20yxuQjjApQX2ZlavkIpqJqFXMlFNROEzOgyqaFm1zRmx6ib46CNlhzU1ImlRAoRVEGo9SQSmzIJuCyQaZN9vLCtigCfqRqnBR33AWKd1FxaUARCK/NcTOINm0gZuiamfmYih0r5GGHzs3/T2zunrWVKKhBooa5qC91DLqmTDb3jnVgZt1AGwlTL47Q2iBOXzZ3l1EW0pAQxRdJshQSgTCFIXDRR%20vcilaLOUMygb8cGC2S4JuYlG43SYfpwm7JliZiEz4CwUtNpSkXGCgfeuKgWeSRNTDRI6myjtD1yNShsxMdd2D5NI99jsNhOK2RJbLmcRyhEaNowGQ5ZkrLB4GVwO0mTyWgcPQyTwf04%20X7y0U1RYCVhum1r1rRhTalDZtyU1Eihw9I%20NwyedrtrTcboSRuUygrAglD3aZrd8dntOG8A9ZhOOAIL4HQ8LnI2S23xHp5wphS%20EFXNwIIv6v2mMWK8yx0CTe0rgzQZJgdJsgawoQbvqqAmJ5QA3BZVR8IB9a603Qqx94pkRztivOEmrEjhva0zrbp4UOekn3RjuSJzpOCnR4q2e9Hp52Z92Zm2nH/wmEMgmRmHztyk/kGmSpAcFAY2Da3pWXduMefN6AC086F/HHvcjtrs/zlRV6/Bjo6Kqi2I0TvAVLpT8zHvaVMd2znP4qj77K3Rn%20uby4u3y4vfPVJOmEIvvC5fz73B3v4CvPN0elwHAAA=)

Comment: Thanks a ton! Oh god, I fell prey to a typo. Sorry for no upvote, I don't have the reputation yet.